# Xamarin (android) database connection error

Tags: c#, mysql, xamarin

i'm begginer in xamarin, but i have to write app. I have to connect to MySQL and update some data. I have written code, whitch works in vs 2013 express, but in Xamarin i have error:

```
 The type 'System.Data.Common.DbConnection' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. (CS0012)
```

What i can do to repair it? - change target framework?

i'm using Mysql.Data.dll

pls for quick answer :)

Answer (score 0):

It says you need to add refference to **System.Data**. It is located in Xamarin Base Class Libraries. Use right click on Refferences "folder" in Xamarin Studio to add refference.

Comment: Thanks, it works :D but i must damage something,,, and i have error... 

Error: Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'System.Configuration.Install, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?

Comment: hmm... maybe it is no my mistake... after add this reference it shows this error, and warning that there is "conflicts between versions of the same dependent assembly"